# How to fix Nginx Caching 404 - Flask?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, nginx, flask, amazon-ec2

**This is my /etc/nginx/conf.d/flaskapp.conf file:**

```
 server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 3.6.233.76;
        location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please explain what your exact issue **related to programming** is!

Comment: Could you please describe your problem in detail?

Comment: When I refresh the page then we got unexpected contains(Old contains which are deleted)  and sometimes it working fine. can you check on my website http://python-ds.com  ?